# SELECT (COUNT(*)) query in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to execute SQL query with table gateway which contain COUNT(*) expression in ZF2. This is function in my model:

```
public function brKomentariUred(){
        $sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->columns(array('brKomentari' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('count(komentarID)'), 'uredId' => 'ured'));
        $select->group('ured');
        //echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select); die();
        return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);      
    }
```

When the query is printed it is correct

```
SELECT count(komentarID) AS `brKomentari`, `komentar`.`ured` AS `uredId` FROM `komentar` GROUP BY `ured`
```

In the controller I'm trying to call the query with this code

```
foreach($this->getKomentarTable()->brKomentariUred() as $r){
                $arr = $this->object_to_array($r);
                print_r($arr);
            }
```

It doesn't return number of elements and devicesID as it is written in SELECT, but return as `SELECT * FROM komentar`, but with no values. Is this right code or I'm making some error in my code? Other queries are OK.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "devicesID as it is written in SELECT" - there's no `devicesID ` column in your query

Comment: I mean 'ured'. 'ured' is column in my table. The result which I get is this
Array
(
    [komentarID] => 
    [datum] => 
    [sodrzina] => 
    [ured] => 
    [korisnik] => 
    [inputFilter] => 
)
Array
(
    [komentarID] => 
    [datum] => 
    [sodrzina] => 
    [ured] => 
    [korisnik] => 
    [inputFilter] => 
)
All of the elements in the arrays, except InputFilter, are columns in my table in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place I would do the following steps:

- replace the expression object with `new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(komentarID)')`
- I wouldn't use an alias in `group by` operator, it may not work. So,
  replace this `$select->group('ured')` with
  `$select->group('komentar.ured')`

Also, the result processing should be simplified:

```
$resultSet = $this->getKomentarTable()->brKomentariUred();
print_r($resultSet->toArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort to help me, I appreciate it. I made the changes, but, unfortunately, it is same result. I'm expecting to get only two columns in the result. I'm stuck on this for all day :@

Comment: I found the solution! In my model I changed $resultSet which is return by the function.
I changed 
    return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
into 
     $resultSet = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
     return $resultSet->execute();
And it works! THANKS again for your time and efforts to help me.